# Android: MediaPlayer finalized without being released

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm using the MediaPlayer class in an app that I'm currently working on.  I want to hold on to an instance of the MediaPlayer class for the lifetime of my Activity.  I'm releasing the resources from the MediaPlayer class in the onPause() { } method of the activity, however when the activity starts I see the following warning pop up in the LogCat window:

```
W/MediaPlayer-JNI(16795): MediaPlayer finalized without being released
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here or how to remove this warning? It doesn't appear to cause any issues and the sound works just fine.

I have a bit too much code to post because I wrapped a few objects to allow state to be managed (the MediaPlayer class doesn't currently provide state information), and various other reasons, but the code is pretty much:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initialiseSounds(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    soundManager.releaseResources();
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    initialiseSounds(this);
}
```

With this method in my SoundManager class:

```
public void releaseResources()
{
    player.release();
}
```

And in initialiseSounds I'm doing:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
player.reset();
player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
AssetFileDescriptor assetFileDescriptor = context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(resourceId);
setDataSource(player, assetFileDescriptor);
```

When I want to play the track I do:

```
player.prepare();
player.start();
```

Appreciate any advice,

Thanks,

Comment: Can you include the relevant code snippets of what you're doing to mediaplayer in onCreate/onResume/onPause, etc? "releasing the resources" could be interpreted somewhat ambiguously.

Comment: @Tim Hi Tim, I've added some code to the question, thanks!

Comment: this answer saved me https://stackoverflow.com/a/59234021/5773037

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not completely sure of the origin of that message, but notice here that you're creating **two** MediaPlayers: one in onCreate and one in onResume.

That message seems to indicate that it doesn't like that a MP is being finalized (GC'd) without being 'released'. It may be referring to that first mediaPlayer you create in onCreate, which is lost after you reassign it in onResume.

Perhaps the error will go away if you only create one MediaPlayer instead of two?

Answer (score 11):

in my case, I have created local media player reference in a method and what I did was that all the time when I want to play some audio I had used that method. but then I figured that after sudden that local variable is gonna clean from the memory and MediaPlayer can't be accessed anymore with that reference.

Then I created a one global static Mediaplayer reference and when ever i create a media player object i initilized it to that static variable and my problem seems to be solved

Comment: my pleasure! tnx for the vote bro... @NikunjParadva

Comment: i always appreciate that answer which is helped me.

Comment: Thank you sir! This was exactly the issue!

Answer (score 8):

This message also appears if you don't call release on the media player object and your fragment is stopped, and destroyed.

You need to override `onStop()` or one of the other methods and call release() on the media player.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have met similar problem  Call the method in onStart() or onResume , Do not call it in onCreate().