# MediaPlayer finalized without being released... Sound is getting stop

Tags: android, media-player, audio

My code is working properly but suddenly sound is getting stop with this error "MediaPlayer finalized without being released"

My Code is

```
public void PLAYSOUND(MediaPlayer Player, boolean value,SOUND sound) throws IllegalArgumentException, SecurityException, IllegalStateException, IOException{

      try {
            AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = null;
            if (Player != null) {
                Player.stop();
                Player.release();
                Player = new MediaPlayer();
            }else
                Player = new MediaPlayer();

            descriptor = GameManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getAssets().openFd("sound/mainmenu.wav");

            //AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = GameManager.getInstance().getCurrentActivity().getAssets().openFd("sound/mainmenu.wav");
            Player.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());    
            Player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

            descriptor.close();

            Player.prepare();
            Player.setLooping(value);
            if(mCheckVolumeOnOff)
                Player.setVolume(2.0f, 2.0f);
            else
                Player.setVolume(2.0f,2.0f);
            Player.start();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

I have checked that sound is not getting stop because of .stop() and .release().

Comment: Check This May This Help You http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15023037/garbage-collection-causes-mediaplayer-finalized-without-being-released

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590435/android-mediaplayer-finalized-without-being-released

Comment: I have checked both... Not useful for me.. Link related video was similar to my issue but solution is for video problems and I want Media Player's solution...

Comment: Where Exactly Error Throw??

Comment: In Logcat... Its not showing like error... Just throwing "MediaPlayer finalized without being released" like this.

Comment: DId you find the solution ? I am facing a similar problem !